# Discrepancy in Results from epiDisplay ordinal.or.display p value and calculated p for polr from MASS package?

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, ordinal, mass

I am trying to calculate Odds Ratios and associated p-values for a set of biomarkers using ordinal logistic regression (specifically, polr from MASS package). I've been using the 'ordinal.or.display()' function from the epiDisplay package to view the results of the regression, but notice a discrepancy between the displayed p-value and what I calculate manually... it's about twice as large when I calculate it using the normal distribution. Am I missing something specific to Ordinal Logistic Regression, or is this an issue with the epiDisplay function?

I tried looking at the documentation for the epiDisplay package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/epiDisplay/epiDisplay.pdf), but didn't find anything that explained how the p-value there was calculated. Any help or additional knowledge is much appreciated!

```r
#the model using polr from MASS
#generating artifical outcome var from mt cars

mtcars <- mtcars
mtcars$outcome <- round(runif(nrow(mtcars))*5)
myMod <-polr(ordered(outcome) ~ factor(am)+ factor(carb)+ wt,
             data = mtcars,
             Hess = TRUE)

summary <- summary(myMod)
(ctable <- coef(summary(myMod)))
p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2

## combined table: p = 0.624
(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p))


ordinal.or.display(myMod) #p value = 0.312
```

I expect the p values to be the same- does epiDisplay perhaps not multiply by two?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the random number seed whenever you simulate data. Otherwise, we can't reproduce your results.

```
set.seed(123)
```

You've used the normal distribution to obtain the p-value when you should be using the t distribution. So your code to calculate the p-value should be:

```
df <- summary(myMod)$df.residual
p <- pt(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), df=df, lower.tail=FALSE) * 2
```

This is also the way the `ordinal.or.display` function from the epiDisplay package does the calculation. You can check by looking at the code at about line 9.

```
library(epiDisplay)
ordinal.or.display
```

Now check:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$outcome <- round(runif(nrow(mtcars))*5)

myMod <- polr(ordered(outcome) ~ factor(am)+ factor(carb)+ wt,
              data = mtcars,
              Hess = TRUE)

ctable <- coef(summary(myMod))

df <- summary(myMod)$df.residual
p <- pt(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), df=df, lower.tail=FALSE) * 2

options(digits=2)

(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value:" = p))

       Value Std. Error t value p value:
am1   -2.335       1.19  -1.962    0.064
carb2  0.045       0.92   0.049    0.961
carb3  1.840       1.40   1.319    0.202
carb4 -0.618       1.16  -0.534    0.599
carb6  1.721       1.85   0.933    0.362
carb8  2.418       2.10   1.152    0.263
wt    -0.875       0.68  -1.295    0.210

ordinal.or.display(myMod)
#Waiting for profiling to be done...
      Ordinal OR lower95ci upper95ci P value
am1   0.097      0.009     0.971     0.064  
carb2 1.046      0.166     6.477     0.961  
carb3 6.298      0.428     112.827   0.202  
carb4 0.539      0.051     5.065     0.599  
carb6 5.59       0.121     273.826   0.362  
carb8 11.218     0.162     864.225   0.263  
wt    0.417      0.106     1.573     0.210
```

Looks the same to me.